# CSS: Border for list of elements, no overlap but highlighting possible

Tags: html, css, border

I've a list of elements with a border. The border should not overlap. But: There may be elements which are invisible, and one element might be highlighted by a different border-color:

```css
#navigation_bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation_bar li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

#navigation_bar li.first {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#navigation_bar li.hilighted {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation_bar">
  <li class="first">Projection</li>
  <li class="hilighted">Real-Time</li>
  <li style="display:none;">Invisible</li>
  <li>Cleanup</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that either the borders overlap, or not the full border is highlighted (as you can see in my example, the bottom-border of "Real-Time" is black, but it should be red).

Any ideas how to do this just using css?

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wk9ydo41/1/

Comment: It's not really clear what effect you want here. You either want borders to overlap or you don't. If you don't, why the negative margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the full highlighted border visible you need to elevate that element with `z-index`. However to use `z-index` you need a non-static positioning. You can use `position: relative` for it:

```css
#navigation_bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation_bar li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

#navigation_bar li.first {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#navigation_bar li.hilighted {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation_bar">
  <li class="first">Projection</li>
  <li class="hilighted">Real-Time</li>
  <li style="display:none;">Invisible</li>
  <li>Cleanup</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works perfectly. Was driving me crazy, I was trying to use an adjacent sibling selectors to remove the border from the next <li>, but that didn't work on the invisible element.

Comment: @Werner position: relative alone should be enough, no need for z-index

Comment: @TemaniAfif is as always right :D